# Perlbal Reproxy with Remote Host

Tags: web-server, configuration, load-balancing

why would perlbal's reproxying give me a 503 for any remote url?

```
X-REPROXY-URL: /path/to/a/local/file.jpg = working
X-REPROXY-URL: http://a-public-file-in-an-s3-bucket.jpg = HTTP 503
```

my perlbal conf looks like:

```
CREATE POOL test_pool
    POOL test_pool ADD 127.0.0.1:8888
    POOL test_pool ADD 127.0.0.1:8889

CREATE SERVICE balancer
    SET listen          = 0.0.0.0:80
    SET role            = reverse_proxy
    SET pool            = test_pool
    SET persist_client  = on
    SET persist_backend = on
    SET verify_backend  = on
    SET enable_reproxy  = true

ENABLE balancer
```

i know im setting the header properly, because, as i said, it works for local files and urls of the same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perlbal route the request trough HTTP so you will the HTTP request need to satisfy webserver's    rules or ACL.

Easiest way to check is to emulate the request using curl :
eg : curl -vv http://127.0.0.1:8888/a-public-file-in-an-s3-bucket.jpg

Check your server access_log or error_log. If you run virtual webserver you might need to specify a FQDN instead of IP addess.

Comment: after playing around with a few variations of the S3 url, i found that it can't handle urls like: 
http://bucket-name-with-hyphens.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/file, but can handle http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name-with-hyphens/path/. how weird is that?

Comment: I've run into the same problem before. BIND and majority of dns name server doesn't really like hyphen or non alphabetical character (except for underscore). If you rename the subdomain with underscore it should work.